# Reading stdout from subprocess from the main process using PIPE causing the death of the subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, stdout, popen

I have a simple code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["/home/root/cc6ul/./IQ-sampler", str(self.num_files), str(self.n), self.results_directory, self.device_id, self.rid, self.cc6ul_state_filepath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while proc.poll() is None:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    self.log.info("line:{}".format(line))
```

This is causing my IQ-sampler process to die before time. But If I run it directly from the terminal it has no problems. I tried debugging this but I don't understand the root cause. 
Is it the communication PIPE that is causing the issues? Since that is the only connection I can see between the 2 processes.

Comment: What does `IQ-sampler` do?

Comment: The IQ-sampler is C code executable that takes in no of files, no of samples per file and collects the I&Q channel data from the ADC connected to a radar sensor through a timer callback. It then stdouts the path of the saved file to the main process after successful collection of each file.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging the problem seems to be in the IQ-sampler linux C timer callback which was using SIGEV_THREAD thread notification. Including the timer callback in critical section using locks seems to have solved this issue.

Whats interesting though is that only when other processes(here main python process) is running the IQ-sampler was dying which leads me to believe that the load on the CPU is probably aggravating the concurrency issues.

Answer (score -1):

If the command does work on the terminal, then you can simply pass in `shell=True` and the actual command into the Popen function. That should have the exact same output as executing the command on the shell.

Comment: I can't see how this would help with the problem the OP described.